# LLC Compiler is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: python, gcc, lexer, llc

Im creating a custom programming language using python, PLY as lexer and parser, and LLVMlite as low level intermediate language to do code generation.
I have installed PLY and LLC using Python pip

I use LLC to create a object file output.o, and GCC to create the final executable file as follows.

```
$ llc -filetype=obj output.ll
$ gcc output.o -o output
```

When im executing `llc -filetype=obj output.ll` i get

```
llc : The term 'llc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,  
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ llc -filetype=obj output.ll
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (llc:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have spent hours on this but cant figure out. What is wrong?

Comment: Sounds like `llc` isnt in your PATH.

Comment: The `llc` python package you installed with pip has nothing to do with llvm. It's a completely different product which happens to have the same name. You need to follow the LLVM installation instructions.

Answer (score 0):

The [PyPi package llc](https://pypi.org/project/llc/) has nothing to do with LLVM's `llc` tool. You can't install the latter via `pip` because it's not a Python package. You need to install the LLVM tools to get it.